# How do I debug Playwright tests from Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, playwright, playwright-dotnet

I'm using MSTest with Playwright in Visual Studio, and am having trouble with a selector. I want to debug using Playwright dev tools, Playwright inspector, etc. This page https://playwright.dev/docs/debug-selectors#using-playwright-inspector suggests setting PWDEBUG=1 or PWDEBUG=console. All the examples show running tests using VS Code, or command line test execution. I'm using Visual Studio 2022 with Test Explorer. Where do I set these variables?

I've tried:

- Using the debug settings environment variables (nothing happens)
- Creating a .runsettings file with the following contents:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
> <RunSettings>
>   <EnvironmentVariables>
>       <PWDEBUG>1</PWDEBUG>
>   </EnvironmentVariables> 
> </RunSettings>
> ```

Then I used Test -> Configure Run Settings to select this file.

Still no debug console.

What am I missing?

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I take this approach:
https://playwright.dev/docs/debug#browser-developer-tools

Just add  `page.pause()` before the step where you need that selector and it will pause execution and allow you to debug

Answer (score 0):

You were so close with your solution.

The correct format for the `debug.runsettings` file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
  <RunConfiguration>
    <EnvironmentVariables>
      <PWDEBUG>1</PWDEBUG>
    </EnvironmentVariables>
  </RunConfiguration>
</RunSettings>
```

Place this file somewhere in your solution and ensure your tests are using it. It should now launch the PlayWright debugger and Chrome window when running or debugging any test in Visual Studio.